# $G$ is a finite group. $A$ and $B$ are non-empty subsets of $G$. If $\vert A\vert+\vert B\vert>\vert G\vert$, prove that $AB=G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Question: Let $G$ be a finite group, $A$ and $B$ non-empty subsets of $G$. Set $AB=\lbrace ab\colon a\in A, b\in B\rbrace$. If $\vert A\vert+\vert B\vert>\vert G\vert$, prove that $AB=G$.

I try to prove inductively on the order of $G$. For $\vert G\vert=1$, it is trivial. Now we assume the proposition holds for $\vert G\vert=n$. If $G$ is not simple, i.e., $G$ contains a nontrivial normal subgroup, namely $N$, the inductive hypothesis can be used as follows:

Make the cannonical maps $f_{A}\colon A\to G/N$, $f_{B}\colon B\to G/N$. We claim that $\vert f\left(A\right)\vert+\vert f\left(B\right)\vert>\vert G/N\vert$. (If this were not the case, i.e., $\vert f\left(A\right)\vert+\vert f\left(B\right)\vert\leq\vert G/N\vert$, $A$ and $B$ together would not "cover" all the cosets of $N$, or they would just happen to "cover" all the cosets. This is contradictory to the assumption that $\vert A\vert+\vert B\vert>\vert G\vert$.) By induction hypothesis, $f\left(A\right)f\left(B\right)=G/N$. It follows that $AB=G$, noticing that $N$ is normal.

What if $G$ is simple? Can it be shown inductively even if $G$ is simple? Or shall we seek an alternative way of proving? THX!

Answer (score 2):

Let $g$ be an arbitrary element of $G$; we want to prove that $g\in AB$.

Consider the set $\{a^{-1}g\mid a\in A\}$. It has $|A|$ elements and therefore must have at least one element in common with $|B|$. So for appropriate $a$ and $b$ we have $b=a^{-1}g$ ...